# Indent UITableView section header when editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I would like to indent my section headers and footers when a UITableView enters editing mode. UITableView does it automatically for the cells but I couldn't find any API to do the same for sections headers/footers. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a mechanism to specifically change the offset of the headers and footers, but you can provide your own custom headers and footers.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/adding_headers_and_footers_to_table_sections

note that the default headers and footers are provide by the class `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` which you may be able to subclass.  That class, in turn, has the method `contentConfiguration` property which defines the current look for the cell.  You might be able to create a custom header view that adopts different content configurations when the table is in editing mode.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Unfortunately I still have to support iOS 12 upwards so contentConfiguration is not an option :(.